# using return to show grades

Tags: python, function, return

I wrote a python code that has a function that takes in the total marks as an input and calculates the grade and I wanna know if I did it right and used the return properly in this code:

```
def get_grades():
    marks = round(float(input('Your Current Marks: ')))
    if marks in range(0,101):
        if marks >=90:
            return("Your Grade is: A+")
        elif marks >=86:
            return("Your Grade is: A")
        elif marks >=82:
            return("Your Grade is: A-")
        elif marks >=78:
            return("Your Grade is: B+")
        elif marks >=74:
            return("Your Grade is: B")
        elif marks >=70:
            return("Your Grade is: B-")
        elif marks >=66:
            return("Your Grade is: C+")
        elif marks >=62:
            return("Your Grade is: C")
        elif marks >=58:
            return("Your Grade is: C-")
        elif marks >=54:
            return("Your Grade is: D+")
        elif marks >=50:
            return("Your Grade is: D")
        else:
            return("Your Grade is: F")
    else:
        return("sorry, your input is out of range")
print(get_grades())
```

Comment: Llooks okay to me, although the paranthesis are not needed.

Comment: @Llna After, not before.

Comment: I would say it depends on the nature of your function. If you plan on using it only for printing the grade, I would replace return("text") with print("text"). Otherwise I see no problem.

Also, you could define "Your Grade is: " as a variable and then reuse it every time you return/ print the string. Remember the DRY principle - don't repeat yourself.

Comment: @MikaelsSlava Printing in such a function is *almost never* a good idea: output and logic should be cleanly separated: one function to calculate grades, another one to format them, a third one to print them. Your suggestion would mix all three steps, or at least the second and third. This is generally considered an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

It's correct insofar as returning the result that your `print` call needs, but note that your function does not take the marks as input (in the sense of a function taking parameters as its input and returning a result as output).  Here is how you might structure the function so that it takes the marks as an input and returns the grade (and only the grade) as its output:

```
def get_grade(marks: int) -> str:
    """Given marks from 0 to 100, return a letter grade from F to A+."""
    if marks not in range(0, 101):
        raise ValueError(f"{marks} is out of range (expected 0-100)")
    if marks >= 90:
        return "A+"
    if marks >= 86:
        return "A"
    if marks >= 82:
        return "A-"
    if marks >= 78:
        return "B+"
    if marks >= 74:
        return "B"
    if marks >= 70:
        return "B-"
    if marks >= 66:
        return "C+"
    if marks >= 62:
        return "C"
    if marks >= 58:
        return "C-"
    if marks >= 54:
        return "D+"
    if marks >= 50:
        return "D"
    return "F"


try:
    grade = get_grade(round(float(input('Your Current Marks: '))))
    print(f"Your Grade is: {grade}")
except ValueError as e:
    print(f"Sorry, invalid input!  {e}")
```

Note that this eliminates a lot of copying and pasting -- the text `Your Grade is:`  doesn't need to be repeated inside the function because now the caller is responsible for formatting the letter grade into the final message for the user.

Structuring your code in this way also makes it easier to test:

```
assert get_grade(90) == "A+"
assert get_grade(10) == "F"
assert get_grade(77) == "B"
try:
    get_grade(-42)
    raise AssertionError("get_grade should raise on invalid input")
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is done right. `return` is for functions, so good job.